# duplicate context menu items when clicked multiple times on same row in JFace table in mac

Tags: jface

I am using Jface table and have a context menu which differs for each row depending on the selected row.

When I click once the context menu is getting displayed fine, but when I click multiple times the context menu is getting added to the previous context menu and getting displayed twice or thrice depending on number of clicks.

This is happening only on mac and not on windows.
Can someone help me in resolving this?

Comment: You are going the have to show us how you are creating and showing the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

You had a similar issue with [Eclipse 4.x using JFace at the time in 2013-2014](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=405262#c23)

> Right click on the second line (you may have to bring the context menu up a few times)
>
> The context menu now shows some (but not all) entries twice: "Remove from Context" and the entries in "Team", "Compare With" and "Replace With" menus

That was [fixed in that commit](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/commit/?id=0221b899798afc05d3b4c96e7fdc15cc35e9a235).

Even though your project might not involve Eclipse, the general reason can give you some clue for your specific project.

> The reason of the problem is that some action contributions computed for the editor and active selection are the same.